# Grids to display SharePoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have SharePoint list with more than 100K items. Due to list view threshold, I am not able to create views and display required items via any OOTB solution. As an another option, I am planning to go with any custom JavaScript based solution to display items on a grid. Can anyone please suggest which are best javascript based grids available in market who can also give features like filtering/searching/sorting of items?

Comment: Shad: Did you expand the list view's threshold on web application's setting? After doing that, we can create view with about 1000 items each page.

Comment: jquery datatable could be an option.

Comment: Have you tried creating view with limited columns or say filtered view. That should work on OOTB.

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your replies.


JohnThomas - Unfortunately we are not allowed to change default threshold limit.

Gaurravs - As minimum records we are expecting will be more than 5000. So even limited columns option will not work as it won't allow to create view in first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQGrid or also datatables as suggested above. JQGrid is a grid plugin for the JQuery Javascript library. It is free, open source and gets distributed under the MIT license.

1) Works fine under IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

2) CSS customizable.

3) The UI comes in 20+ languages.

4) Paging and sorting

5) Search and filtering

6) In-place cell editing or on-the-fly form creation to edit a record

7) Supports subgrids and tree grid for displaying hierarchical data

8) AJAX enabled

9) Accepts XML/JSON/local array data sources

You may refer to following links for its information,

http://jqgrid.com/

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: jqgrid worked. We also tried Ng grid. We are planning to go with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Kendo IU Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) by Telerik. It's simple to use and contains filter, search and sort options. But I think the problem will be to get list data from SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks. We are looking for any free option first. In case if we could not achieve required functionality then only we may explore any paid third party solution.